# Include plots but not console in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

When I knit in R markdown, I not only get the nice plots I want to display but also little console displays like this above each and every plot:

```
## $`2FL`
## $`2FL`$Timepoint
```

I have tried include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, and message=FALSE to no avail.

When I try results='hide' I don't get the plots I want.

Does anyone know how to show only the plot output and not annoying little console things like this? I would have thought message=FALSE would work but like I said it didn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `results='hide'` does not suppress the plot. Do you set `include=FALSE` with it? Try to use `results='hide'` alone.

Comment: Can you show an example? It is quite hard to test options just with your description

Comment: Thank you @DarrenTsai - you're right. Thanks so much.